# Android: Next and previous button for activity using different images

Tags: android, onclicklistener, buttonclick

The XML file for Full Image Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="800">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:weightSum="200">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Previous"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/Next"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final GridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
               }
        });
```

And this is my Full Image Activity Class

```
ImageAdapter imageAdapter; ImageView imageView;
int position;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image_layout);

    Button next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Next);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    position = i.getExtras().getInt("id"); 

    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position] > imageAdapter.mThumbIds.length - 1) {
                position++;
                imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
            }
            else{
                Log.d("TAG", "Reached Last Record");
            }
            if(position < imageAdapter.mThumbIds.length - 1) {
                position++;
            }
            else{
                Log.d("TAG", "Reached Last Record");
            }
        }
    });
```

How and where should I implement Next and Previous button logic in order to get things going.
Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: I want next and previous button implementation... after bringing some image on front, i want next and previous button to bring the next or previous image from the array.. The code i wrote for this logic doesn't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out ... Needs listener which keep incrementing or decremented the array holding images.

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[++position]);
}});

previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[--position]);
}});
```

Comment: How to do this in Listview or in Recyelerview items ?

Answer (score 0):

For Multiple Array Use the Below Code

```
int n;
for Next button 
if (n>=int_Info.length)
{
   Toast.makeText(this, "Last", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else {
   Glide.with(this).load(int_Info[n++]).into(zoomageView);
}
```